# Сортировка TreeSet | java

Tags: java, сортировка, дерево

Как создать `TreeSet` объекта какого либо класса, отсортированное по значению переменной объекта этого класса? К примеру есть класс `User`:

```
class User {
    String name;
    int age;

    User(String n, int a) {
        name = n;
        age = a;
    }
}
```

В классе `Main` необходимо создать дерево объектов `User` отсортированное по переменной `name`
Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set<User> users = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(User::getName));
users.add(new User("Alex", 25));
users.add(new User("Mike", 40));
users.add(new User("Boris", 34));
System.out.println(users);
```

Вывод:

```
[User{name='Alex', age=25}, User{name='Boris', age=34}, User{name='Mike', age=40}]
```

**UPD 1** (из комментария): при отсутствии геттера и при условии, что класс package-private и расположен в одном пакете с вызывающим классом:

```
Set<User> users = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(u -> u.name));
```

**UPD 2** (из комментария): вариант без лямбд

```
Set<User> users = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<User>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(User o1, User o2) {
        return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
    }
});
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что следуя условиям задания мне нельзя вносить изменения в класс `User`, следовательно геттер `getName` я реализовать не могу

Comment: Класс User какую область видимости имеет?

Comment: ничего не указано значит `default`

Comment: расположен в одном пакете с main?

Comment: Да, в одном пакете

Comment: добавил в ответ

Comment: А можно без использования лямбда-выражения? Просто еще не знаю, как они используются

Comment: добавил в ответ

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста. [Если ответ вам помог](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)